# PHP Value Repeat Twice

Tags: javascript, php, sql

My project so far I'm grabbing data from my SQL table. I have four different sections which all grab the same information from the same table.

The first section works great. The data is there.

The next three sections works, BUT the data repeats itself which I don't understand why or how I can fix it. Below are my SQL table and my php code.

```
+--------+
| Color  |
+--------+
| Red    |
| Blue   |
| Orange |
| Black  |
+--------+


+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| GroupName | MemberName   | ValueName |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| Red       | Joe Bob      | Joe       |
| Red       | Catherine    | Kat       |
| Blue      | Tommy        | Tom       |
| Orange    | John Razks   | John      |
| Black     | Trevor Smith | Trevor    |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

Code:

```
<form id=#blah>
     <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
     <option value="">Select Color</option>
     <?php
     $conn = mysqli_connect("#connection");

    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed".myslqi_connect_error());
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from Color order by Color ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        unset($committee, $Committee);
        // $committee = $row['Committee'];
        $Committee = $row['Color'];
        echo '<option value=" .$Committee. ">'.$Committee.'</option>';
    }
    ?>  
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
        Individual: 
        <select name="senator" id="senator">
        <option value="">Select Individual</option>
        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("#connection");

    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed".myslqi_connect_error());
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT distinct MemberName,GroupName,ValueName from Members order by MemberName ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $array[$row['GroupName']][] = $row;
    }
    foreach($array as $class => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo "<optgroup class=".$class.">";
            foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                echo "<option value=".$v['ValueName'].">".$v['MemberName']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</optgroup>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </form>
    <form id=#id>
        <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("#connection");

    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed".myslqi_connect_error());
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from Color order by Color ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        unset($committee, $Committee);
        // $committee = $row['Committee'];
        $Committee = $row['Color'];
        echo '<option value=" .$Committee. ">'.$Committee.'</option>';
    }
    ?>  
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
        Individual: 
        <select name="senator" id="senator">
        <option value="">Select Individual</option>
        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect("#connection");

    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed".myslqi_connect_error());
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT distinct MemberName,GroupName,ValueName from Members order by MemberName ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $array[$row['GroupName']][] = $row;
    }
    foreach($array as $class => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo "<optgroup class=".$class.">";
            foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                echo "<option value=".$v['ValueName'].">".$v['MemberName']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</optgroup>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the duplication comes from using the same variable names in your loops when recalling the same query the second time or it could also be something happening in the loops.
I think you could avoid this and make the code a bit neater by running each query only once and then call the data each time you need to use it:

```
<?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db_name");
  if(!$conn){ die("Connection Failed".myslqi_connect_error()); }
  else{
    $color_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from Color order by Color ASC");
    $colors = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_result)){ $colors[] = $row['Color']; }
    $member_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT distinct MemberName,GroupName,ValueName from Members order by MemberName ASC");
    $members = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($member_result)){
      if(!isset($members[$row['GroupName']])){ $members[$row['GroupName']] = array(); }
        $members[$row['GroupName']][] = $row; }
  }
?>
<form id=#blah>
<select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
        <?php
            foreach($colors as $color){
              echo "<option value=\"".$color."\">".$color."</option>";
            }
         ?> 
            </select>
        </div>

    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
    Individual: 
    <select name="senator" id="senator">
        <option value="">Select Individual</option>
        <?php
        foreach($members as $key => $member_group){
                echo "<optgroup class=\"".$key."\">";
                foreach($member_group as $val){
                    echo "<option value=\"".$val['ValueName']."\">".$val['MemberName']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</optgroup>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  </form>
  <form id=#id>
  <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Select Color</option>
        <?php
            foreach($colors as $color){
              echo "<option value=\"".$color."\">".$color."</option>";
            }
         ?> 
            </select>
        </div>

    <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
    Individual: 
    <select name="senator" id="senator">
        <option value="">Select Individual</option>
        <?php
        foreach($members as $key => $member_group){
                echo "<optgroup class=".$key.">";
                foreach($member_group as $val){
                    echo "<option value=\"".$val['ValueName']."\">".$val['MemberName']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</optgroup>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  </form>
```

This should let you get the desired output while only having to run each query once and should eliminate the duplication. I hope this helps

Comment: well it comes back for colors as "array","array","array","array"

Comment: @catung555555 - Sorry I stored the row value instead of the column, I adjusted it to select the color column value at the top after running the query

Comment: Thank you very much, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @catung555555 - Sure thing, please accept as answer if this helped you.

Comment: I do have another question. Where would I place the main PHP code if I want to add a header. Once I add something in the header, the code doesnt work.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you can execute the top php block anywhere before your form so that the data is stored before you call it in the output loops. You could place it at the very top of your page if you want. All I can think of is what you added caused a php error which prevented the rest of the code from running. What did you add above it?

Comment: @catung555555 That shouldn't have any affect on the PHP code unless the code block was altered or other PHP written in the header caused errors. This might constitute a separate question at this point since the entire page code would be needed to understand the problem without knowledge of any error messages.

Comment: actually I do have a question, if my value for SQL is two words with a space, why doesn't it grab both? It only grabs the first word.